# Missing assembly reference error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've SharePoint farm solution which was working fine in visual studio 2008, but as I created new project in VS2010 and included existing project then I get the following error and I was unable to resolve it

**The type or namespace name 'Nintex' could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

same error for sharepoint assembly

what I'm missing here? I do have dll of SharePoint and Nintex included in my project but still error is displayed. Please have a look in the attached picture for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: I would like to hear you say that you restarted VS, did a Build|CleanSolution and then a Build|Rebuild. When that doesn't work, post the Build log from the Output window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need update version of Nintex for vs 2010, I am suggesting this assuming that you haven't tried that yet.

Comment: from where I can download updated Nintex.Workflow dll file Microsoft.SharePoint.dll files??

Comment: Got it it was in Program File :P
Thanks for your answer